# How do I find inverse tangent of 2/3 using a triangle?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the inverse tangnet of 2/3 without using a calculator.

I drew a triangle (see attached). I'm blanking out on how to find the inverse tangent since it is not an exact value that is known (pi/6, pi/4, pi/3, pi/2).

Help!

[image: triangle for inverse tan]

Comment: I guess, you forgot to attach the link?

Comment: Taylor series might help, if you're allowed to use any method.

Comment: oops it's not uploading for some reason but i just drew a triangle with sides 2 and 3 and a hypotenuse of root 13

Comment: The triangle is fine, but $\tan^{-1}(2/3)$ is not a "nice" angle.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: It *can* be nicer than the number $\pi$.

Comment: i know it's not nice i'm sad lol but i need it for an intergral problem grrr

Comment: What is the integral problem?  There may be another approach.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real "simple form" for $\arctan(2/3)$.  You have set up the triangle nicely, but there's not much you can do from this point except a numeric approximation (e.g. Taylor Series).

For this integral problem, it's probably best just to leave this as $\arctan(2/3)$, or if that's too much writing, just call it some unclaimed constant (e.g. $\alpha$).